# How to get Mailbox Folder Permissions with SamAccountName or UPN?

Tags: exchange-2010, scripting, powershell

I need to collect and store the folder permissions for each folder in each mailbox of our Exchange system. I'm already aware of the Cmdlet `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` but it has a serious problem.

The objects returned by `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` are a tuple of (User, AccessRights, FolderName). <strike>However, the "User" identity isn't an object, it's just a simple string representing the DisplayName of a user.</strike> (Edit: This was incorrect. See answer for details.).

However, **display names are not necessarily unique** in an Exchange deployment. In our forest, there are over a dozen mailboxes that have identical display names. Therefore, the results from `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` are ambiguous, and don't uniquely identify a single user or mailbox.

How can I get permissions on mailbox folders in an unambiguous way? I would like the ability to reassign them later using `Add-MailboxFolderPermission`, ideally with the UPN.

Comment: FWIW, it appears that people on Office 365 complain of this very issue (with user being the samaccountname).  You might be able to create a script that grabs it, parses the user and looks up the UPN for that samaccountname, and then returns what you want.  But you might end up having to do the reverse for your "Add" idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tinkering with this for a couple hours, it looks like I was wrong. The cmdlet to get permissions on folder mailboxes actually does provide everything in the `User.ADRecipient` property.

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission "username:\Foldername" |
  Foreach-Object {
    $_.User.ADRecipient.UserPrincipalName
  }
```

I discovered this by outputting the results using `Export-Clixml` which created a very large XML file. Now I know that can be a useful technique for seeing what you actually have available.

Comment: But if you ever needed to resolve a DisplayName into a UserPrincipalName, you could do something [like this](http://pastebin.com/MQPLJ5pC).